# PHP Singleton: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting

Tags: php, singleton

I am writing a custom PHP Application from scratch and for some classes I use the [singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), because I need some information to be calculated one time and them I just use them.

Today I wrote a big part of my application and when I tested it all in all, it threw me the following error:

> Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting.

I did some tests and found that error is generated by something like this:

#### File *index.php*

```
class Foo
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        if(!class_exists('Bar', false))
        {
            require 'Bar.php';
        }

        $bar = new Bar;
        $bar->doSomething();
    }

    public function showSomeInformation()
    {
        // information
    }
}

function F()
{
    static $instance = null;

    if(is_null($instance))
    {
        $instance = new Foo;
    }

    return $instance;
}

F();
```

#### File *Bar.php*

```
class Bar
{
    public function doSomething()
    {
        F()->showSomeInformation();
    }
}
```

*To my mind it is valid because `F()` was called before and it should have the instance of Foo in the static variable, and I believe it should somehow work, but it doesn't.*

I feel lost now. How can I make it to work or at least how can I change something to have similar behavior?

Comment: Have a look at `$instance`, it gets evaluated as null every time.

Comment: @Dennis, obviously this is the reason, but why? It is static, it should keep it's value. And why if in index.php i have F(); F(); the $instance value is null only once?

Comment: No. It remains null. It remains in a circular situation... It tries to init Foo but Foo is calling F again which then tries to init Foo again. Foo never has the chance to finish the initialization. Only if it finishes the initialization `$instance` will have a value different from null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$instance` value remains `null` all the time. Why? Well have a look what happens before you assign the instance to `$instance`.

Before `$instance` has any different value you call `$bar->doSomething();` again.

This means you run `F()` again but `$instance` is still `null`. Now you instantiate `Foo` again but guess what `$instance` is still null.

Try this:

```
<?php class Foo
{
    static $instance = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        if(!class_exists('Bar', false))
        {
            require 'Bar.php';
        }

        self::$instance = $this;

        $bar = new Bar;
        $bar->doSomething(self::$instance);
    }

    public function showSomeInformation()
    {
        // information
    }
}

class Bar
{
    public function doSomething($instance)
    {
        F($instance)->showSomeInformation();
    }
}

function F($instance = null)
{
    if(is_null($instance))
    {
        $instance = new Foo;
    }

    return $instance;
}

F();
```

If you use the [singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), make sure the class itself keeps track of whether it got initialized or not. Letting an external source handle this can cause a lot of problems (as you just experienced).

Comment: Thank you. Today I will make big changes to my Application

Answer (score 0):

The infinite recursion happens in the constructor of *foo*:

```
function F()
{
    static $instance = null;

    if(is_null($instance))
    {
        $instance = new Foo;
        echo("Never reached\n");
        if( is_null($instance) )
        {
            echo("Still null!\n");
        }
    }

    return $instance;
}
```

The first *F();* call will not create a Foo. It will call the constructor for Foo, which will call F() before returning the Foo object, but F() calls the constructor on yet another Foo, which will do the same, forever, so no new Foo will ever return from F(). So we run out of stack.

Here's an example of a sane singleton-pattern in PHP: *[Design Patterns](http://www.phptherightway.com/pages/Design-Patterns.html)*

Comment: Yes, because even if showSomeInformation() contains nothing, I also get that error

Comment: You are right, I just checked your example, I will correct my answer when I have found the cause.

Comment: ok, thank you. And even if in doSomething() is just F(); without any method call, it also doesn't work

Comment: Corrected, trick is, that new Foo cannot ever return, since the constructor never finishes, there's the infinite recursion. $instance is not assigned before the constructor returns, which it can't.

Comment: Yes, tha'ts right. I didn't think that it never reaches return $instance. Thank you. I will try to solve this problem somehow

Answer (score 0):

I don't like the [singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) and I guess, if you have a bit experience and begin with unit testing, you will also hate it. But the pattern does not work like you tried it.

```
class MySingletonClass
{
    private static $instance;

    // Make the constructor protected, to prevent direct instantiation
    protected function __construct() {}

    /**
    * @return MySingletonClass
    */
    public static function getInstance()
    {
         if (!self::$instance) {
             self::$instance = new self(); // new static() would we valid too, relevant for extending (late state binding)
         }
         return self::$instance;
    }

    public function getSomething()
    {
         if (!$this->calculated) {
             $this->calculated = $this->calculateSomething();
         }
         return $this->calculated;
    }
}

echo MySingletonClass::getInstance()->getSomething();
```